# Windows 10 Clone post replication tasks

Tags: windows-10, clone, clonezilla

I have a Windows-10 Clonezilla backup image of PC#1.  If PC#2 is outfitted with the same backup image, what post installation tasks must be performed so that they can coexist on the same LAN?  Is there a good list of said task posted somewhere?

Comment: How about run sysprep before the image creation and shutdown. Then spin it up with Clonezilla and make the image with the sysprep'd image on the disk. This way when you image a new hard drive, it comes up asking you for PC name and the usual stuff when you get a new Windows machine with it preinstalled. This will also take care of the SID issue or whatever too which is sometimes a concern with domain/AD environment even though for Windows 10, it shouldn't really be an issue (only domain controllers, etc.) but people are still concerned about matching machine SIDs still sometimes.

Comment: This is how I'd approach it more than likely with Clonezilla, Symantec Ghost, or whatever imaging solution you use for Windows 10 client workstations. Easy enough for you to test to confirm all works as expected as well. Not sure how many flavor builds you have, but consider that my quick advice.

Comment: A list consists of the usual things to make more than one PC work on the same LAN though. No dupe IP addresses, no dupe computer names, etc. There is also an unattended answer file method you can use that will run post installation tasks after a sysprep'd Windows machine shuts down after it's next reboot. You provide tasks in an XML file in the system prep folder or subfolder; you can google to figure it out though. So create the unattend file and drop it to the machine before you sysprep it, now sysprep with 'generalize' and and then shutdown. Make image of that before any boot up and push.

Comment: So what's up with this, what ever came out of it? Did you try sysprep beforehand, did it work for your needs?